# Create a Record Action on Custom Object not showing on of its child custom object

Tags: salesforce1-app, publisher, global-actions

I have a custom object as parent which has 7 child objects. I want to create a custom action for Salesforce1 using Action of type "Create a record". Generally it shows all child records on which we can create a record.

But in my case out of 7 custom objects 6 custom objects are available in "Create a record" action and one object is not visible on custom object list. All child records are connected with lookup only.

I believe that it is an admin configuration issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. The reason ended up being that the child object already had a master-detail relationship to another SObject.

Once this was removed, it was possible to create the Action. Could this have been your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the first thing you should check is if the permissions on the culprit child object are different from the other 6 child objects.

Comment: I compared permission for all objects, they are same. Can you specify the permission which can prevent child record to add in Action Create Record.